# Want to get contents inside a div via php

Tags: php, wordpress, html

Okay, so I been trying to get specific content from different div classes to put in a table.  I'm am customizing my wordpress site.  Here is the code I'm having trouble with

```
//loops through posts
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
       $doc = new DomDocument;
       $doc ->validateOnParse = true;
        $link =  " ' " .  get_permalink()  . " ' "; 
          //this is where the trouble lies.  get error 
          /*Warning: file_get_contents( ' http://www.uwarc.org/?p=60 ' ) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/uwarco5/public_html/wp-content/themes/thesis_185/custom/custom_post_loop.php on line 98

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Empty string supplied as input in /home/uwarco5/public_html/wp-content/themes/thesis_185/custom/custom_post_loop.php on line 98 */

    $doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents( $link ));
    echo "<tr onclick=" . $quote . "DoNav(". $quote1 . "get_post_class('site', null)  " . $quote1.  ");" . $quote . ">" ;
    echo "<td align =" . $quote . "center" . $quote . " >" ;
    echo "<div id =". $quote . "org_logo" . $quote . "> <img src =". $quote ; 
    var_dump($doc->getElementByClass('img')) ;
    echo $quote . "width = ".$quote. '150' . $quote. "; </div> " ;
    the_title();
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . var_dump($doc->getElementByClass('courses')) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    var_dump($doc->getElementByClass('description')); 
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>
      endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Try `$doc->loadHTMLFile( trim( $link));` instead of `$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents( $link ));`.

Comment: Read the error message, you have supplied the wrong link, and there is no file to open. A permalink isn't necessarily a link to a file. Also, loadHTMLFile() get's the file, and does not accept a string.

Comment: The link is correct...I have checked it multiple times.  permalink is a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the post content:

```
$doc->loadHTML( apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ) );
```